# Getting syntax error, unexpected end of file on my registration page

Tags: php, html

So I made a registration page in php and I am getting this. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/signup.php on line 36.

Here is full code.

```
<?php

    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
    define('DB_NAME', 'Users');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', ''); 

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
    $db = mysql_select_db('Users',$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 

    function NewUser() {
        $fullname = $_POST['name'];
        $userName = $_POST['user'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['pass']; 

        $query = "INSERT INTO Users (fullname,userName,email,pass) VALUES ('$fullname','$userName','$email','$password')"; 
        $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        if($data) {
            echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
        }

    }

    function SignUp() {
        if(!empty($_POST['user'])) 
?>

  <!DOCTYPE HTML> <html> 
 <head> 
 <title>Sign-Up</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head> 
  <body id="body-color"> 
 <div id="Sign-Up"> 
 <fieldset style="width:30%">
 <legend>Registration Form</legend> 
 <table border="0"> <tr> 
 <form method="POST" action="connectivity-sign-up.php"> 
 <td>Name</td><td> <input type="text" name="name"></td> 
 </tr> <tr> <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"></td> 
  </tr> <tr> <td>UserName</td><td> <input type="text" name="user"></td>
  </tr> <tr> <td>Password</td><td> <input type="password" name="pass">
  </td> </tr> 
  <tr> <td>Confirm Password </td>
  <td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td> </tr>
   <tr> <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up"></td> 
   </tr> </form> </table> </fieldset> </div> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a good IDE and you get your code properly intended, see the errors faster and they also get shown to you.

Comment: did you forget to put } after `if(!empty($_POST['user'])) `  ? your function doesnt have the second curly brace

Comment: line 36 is the last line, the </html>

Comment: When I put a curly brace there I get syntax error unexpected }

Comment: I use textwrangler to write my code, what ide would you suggest for mac?

Comment: Never mind I got it done thx anyways

Comment: You should really take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) the code you are using is vulnerable to sqlinjection.